# Azure DevOps. Reference Pipeline Settings in PowerShell

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to reference a user who ran pipeline and indicate that a previous specific task in multi-stage pipeline ran successfully or not in a PowerShell script. How can I do that?
Something like:

```
Write-Host $env:UserThatRanPipeline $env:Task:BuildApp1:SuccessOrFail
```

So I'd get output:

```
John Smith Success
```

Comment: For the user you can use `Build.RequestedFor` variable, but I don't think you have variables for each task status, you should create them in each task with some logic.

Comment: Hi, what does it mean `a previous specific task`, would it always be one build/nuget task? Or this time you want to monitor one build task, another time monitor one cmd task?

Comment: I have multi-stage pipelines with 10 stages and 15 tasks in each stage. I'd like to know status of one of the tasks in one of the stages. Specifically `- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4`

Comment: For now azure devops service doesn't provide predefined variable or task to get the status of one specific task, that's why we have to try to find a workaround. If you do want one feature like this, consider posting a feature request in our user voice forum, [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). It would be good to share your idea with our product team :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to reference a user who ran pipeline and indicate that a
>   previous specific task in multi-stage pipeline ran successfully or not
>   in a PowerShell script.

1.Just as **Shayki Abramczyk** suggests above, you can use `Build.RequestedFor` to output the user who runs the pipeline. See [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables), you can use something like: `Write-Host $(Build.RequestedFor)`

2.To get status of your `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task, for now there's no predefined variable available to do that job. So you have to do that with some logic...

**As a workaround:**

You can set one variable `SuccessOrFail: 'Succeed'` like this in yml:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  SuccessOrFail: 'Succeed'
```

And then add one powershell task right after your `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: failed()
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # This script will run only when any previous task failed

      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SuccessOrFail]Fail"
```

3.Make sure there's no custom condition set for your `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task. As I know this task is not a independent task, so it will run when all previous tasks succeed.

**To sum up:**

This ps script will run when `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task failed or skipped, and it will reset the value of `SuccessOrFail` to Fail. So if your `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` succeeds, the value of `$(SuccessOrFail)` is `Succeed`, if it fails or skips, the value would be `Fail`.

Now the value `Succeed` represents the task should certainly succeed, and if the value is `Fail`, it actually represents your task is `NotSucceed`(Fail+Skip).

The order of your tasks should be: `other tasks =>`AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4`=> PS task above=> other tasks => Your own Powershell Task`.